# How can i optimize the query to get values based on each ID?

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join, query-optimization

I would like to get price values from table B to table A for each related ID in table A. My target is to bring prices side by side for six times which are lower than price in table A based on ID order in table B and if there is no any lower price i bring the same price value.

I have already written a query that works but I would like to know how to optimize it.

In the query I have written, I used left join for six times to get value of each ID for table A from table B.

So is there any other way to write this query rather than joining the same table six times?

Table A:

```
|Price| |ID||ID_1||ID_2||ID_3||ID_4||ID_5||ID_6|

|129.90| |1| |1|   |1|   |1|   |1|   |1|    |1|
|149.90| |2| |1|   |1|   |1|   |1|   |1|    |1|
|199.90| |3| |2|   |1|   |1|   |1|   |1|    |1|
|249.90| |4| |3|   |2|   |1|   |1|   |1|    |1|
|299.90| |5| |4|   |3|   |2|   |1|   |1|    |1|
|399.90| |6| |5|   |4|   |3|   |2|   |1|    |1|
```

Table B:

```
| Price ||PriceID|  

|129.90|  |1|  
|149.90|  |2|  
|199.90|  |3|   
|249.90|  |4|   
|299.90|  |5|   
|399.90|  |6|
```

Query:

```
>      SELECT i.*, 
              f.Price AS  NewPrice1, 
              f1.Price AS NewPrice2, 
              f2.Price AS NewPrice3,
              f3.Price AS NewPrice4, 
              f4.Price AS NewPrice5, 
              f5.Price AS NewPrice6
>      FROM #TableA i
>       LEFT JOIN #TableB f ON  i.ID_1 = f.PriceID      
        LEFT JOIN #TableB f1 ON i.ID_2 = f1.PriceID     
        LEFT JOIN #TableB f2 ON i.ID_3 = f2.PriceID     
        LEFT JOIN #TableB f3 ON i.ID_4 = f3.PriceID     
        LEFT JOIN #TableB f4 ON i.ID_5 = f4.PriceID     
        LEFT JOIN #TableB f5 ON i.ID_6 = f5.PriceID
```

Output:

```
|Price| |ID||ID_1||ID_2||ID_3||Price_1||Price_2||Price_3||Price_4||Price_5||Price_6|

|129.90| |1| |1|   |1|   |1| |129.90|  |129.90| |129.90||129.90||129.90||129.90|
|149.90| |2| |1|   |1|   |1| |129.90|  |129.90| |129.90||129.90||129.90||129.90|
|199.90| |3| |2|   |1|   |1| |149.90|  |129.90| |129.90||129.90||129.90||129.90|
|249.90| |4| |3|   |2|   |1| |199.90|  |149.90| |129.90||129.90||129.90||129.90|
|299.90| |5| |4|   |3|   |2| |249.90|  |199.90| |149.90||129.90||129.90||129.90|
|399.90| |6| |5|   |4|   |3| |299.90|  |249.90| |199.90||129.90||129.90||129.90|
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: it's seams to be SQL Server (MSSQL) syntax @jarlh `#TableA` is invalid MySQL syntax.. i removed the MySQL tag for that reason.

Comment: I am using MS SQL Server. Sorry not to mention about it.

Comment: The "problem" was you also tagged MySQL but don't worry about it.

Comment: I have edited the tags. Sorry once again.

Comment: The best solution would be to use normalisation incrementing columns names are a great candidate for that.. But i assume a application is already using this table?

Comment: Yes it's been already using so I am not able to normalize the columns.

Comment: Given that the same data is in both tables and that your SQL has temporary tables, this looks like the second half of a solution.  Could you please add your original table structure and data to your question?

Comment: My original table includes about 50 columns, that's why i had to drop most of them.

Answer (score 1):

Below another angle to look at it:

```
DECLARE @A TABLE
(
    Price INT,
    ID_1 INT,
    ID_2 INT,
    ID_3 INT
)
INSERT INTO @A
(
    Price,
    ID_1,
    ID_2,
    ID_3
)
VALUES
(129.90, 1, 1, 1),
(199.90, 2, 1, 1),
(249.90, 3, 2, 1),
(299.90, 4, 4, 3),
(399.90, 6, 5, 4)


DECLARE @B TABLE
(
    Price INT,
    PriceID INT
)
INSERT INTO @B
(
    Price,
    PriceID
)
VALUES
(129.90, 1),  
(149.90, 2),  
(199.90, 3),   
(249.90, 4),  
(299.90, 5),   
(399.90, 6)

SELECT
    a.Price,
    SUM(b.NewPrice1),
    SUM(b.NewPrice2),
    SUM(b.NewPrice3)
FROM @A a
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN PriceID = a.ID_1 THEN Price ELSE NULL END AS  NewPrice1,
        CASE WHEN PriceID = a.ID_2 THEN Price ELSE NULL END AS  NewPrice2,
        CASE WHEN PriceID = a.ID_3 THEN Price ELSE NULL END AS  NewPrice3
    FROM @B
) b
GROUP BY a.Price
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below query.

```
SELECT
  i.*,
  (SELECT
    f.Price
  FROM #TableB f
  WHERE i.ID_1 = f.PriceID)
  AS NewPrice1,
  (SELECT
    f1.Price
  FROM #TableB f1
  WHERE i.ID_2 = f1.PriceID)
  AS NewPrice2,
  (SELECT
    f2.Price
  FROM #TableB f2
  WHERE i.ID_3 = f2.PriceID)
  AS NewPrice3,
  (SELECT
    f3.Price
  FROM #TableB f3
  WHERE i.ID_4 = f3.PriceID)
  AS NewPrice4,
  (SELECT
    f4.Price
  FROM #TableB f4
  WHERE i.ID_5 = f4.PriceID)
  AS NewPrice5,
  (SELECT
    f5.Price
  FROM #TableB f5
  WHERE i.ID_6 = f5.PriceID)
  AS NewPrice6
FROM #TableA i
```